# running code that replaces placeholder text on each razor view MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

If I had the following razor pages:
*(Excuse the terrible examples..)*

Page1.cshtml

```
Hello @Model.Name, welcome to {sitename}
```

Page2.cshtml

```
{sitename} has had @Model.visitorcount today
```

And at runtime I wanted to replace `{sitename}` with "Contoso" (this var comes from a settings class) as well as additional tags

I could use jQuery with something like:

```
"$(body).replace("{sitename}", "Contoso")
```

this could happen in the `_layout` or `ViewStart` file to cut down on script, but I don't like this approach. Seems like it could cause a lot of code clutter and doesnt "seem right"

is there a better approach to take here? Perhaps using a controller base class and somehow parsing each view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ViewBag in conjunction with a global filter.

E.g.

Page1.cshtml

```
Hello @Model.Name, welcome to @ViewBag.SiteName
```

Page2.cshtml

```
@ViewBag.SiteName has had @Model.visitorcount today
```

SiteNameIntoViewBagAttribute.cs

```
public class SiteNameIntoViewBagAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.SiteName = GetSiteTitle();
    }
}
```

Then register it in global.asax

```
public partial class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        //Blah blah blah

        GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new SiteNameIntoViewBagAttribute ());

        //Blah blah blah
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I considered `Viewbag` but hadn't played with the global filters before, I had no idea it was so easy. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The normal approach would be to add sitename either your ViewModel or ViewBag - that is essentially what they are for.  I believe any other solution will end up putting logic into the view that really belongs in the controller.